# Can gradlew run my espresso tests, not just the "unit" tests?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, gradlew

Android Studio extrudes a script called `gradlew` which can, after much thrashing, run my "unit" tests with `gradlew test`.

Can it run the espresso tests? The ones that actually test your Android?

I seem to think the point of tests is you run them in a batch, and collect 0 or a positive integer to the environment, if they pass or fail.

Apologies for the simple question but Google keeps stemming "gradlew" to "gradle," then returning all kinds of pages about everything but the "gradlew" command itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackOverflow search doesn't stem: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgradlew%5D+espresso

The answer is `./gradlew test connectedAndroidTest`, which apparently runs both batches, and might report faults in either one of them. I don't know if it returns non-zero to the environment if it fails yet...

Comment: You do not need `test`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` to only run the Espresso tests. It will return a non-zero if it fails.